# Why does using __slots__ slow down this code?

Tags: python, performance, class, time, slots

I read in [Usage of __slots__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots) that using `__slots__` in Python can actually save time. But, when I tried to find the time taken using `datetime`, the results were contrary.

```
import datetime as t

class A():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

t1 = t.datetime.now()
a = A(1,2)
t2 = t.datetime.now()
print(t2-t1)
```

... gave output: `0:00:00.000011`
And using slots:

```
import datetime as t

class A():
    __slots__ = 'x','y'
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

t1 = t.datetime.now()
a = A(1,2)
t2 = t.datetime.now()
print(t2-t1)
```

... gave output: `0:00:00.000021`

Using slots actually took longer. Why do we need to use `__slots__` then?

Comment: I'd note that manually using `datetime` in this way isn't the recommended method for timing code. There's [a module meant for timing code snippets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html). And (as mentioned in an answer) you _must_ repeat short operations many times to get anything approaching a meaningful result.

Answer (score 21):

`__slots__` can save time (depends on Python version), but that's not usually what you use it for. What it really saves is memory. Instead of a `__dict__` of fairly large size for every instance, you store attributes directly in the C struct backing the object, and the class itself stores a single copy of the lookup table mapping from names to struct offsets for each attribute. Even on modern Py3 x64 with key-sharing dicts, it's still 96 bytes for a key-sharing `__dict__` where the class has a single instance attribute, on top of the 56 bytes for the object structure itself.

By using `__slots__`, you eliminate the 16 bytes for the pointers to the `__dict__` and `__weakref__` attributes, and eliminate the `__dict__` entirely.

For comparison on Py 3.5:

```
>>> class Foo:
...    def __init__(self, x): self.x = x
...
>>> sys.getsizeof(Foo(1)) + sys.getsizeof(Foo(1).__dict__)
152
>>> class Foo:
...    __slots__ = 'x',
...    def __init__(self, x): self.x = x
...
>>> sys.getsizeof(Foo(1))  # With __slots__, doesn't have __dict__ at all
48
```

That's a savings of over 100 bytes per-instance; on Py2 (w/o key sharing dictionaries) the savings are even greater.

So it's not that `__slots__` is faster in general (it's usually pretty similar), but if you're making millions of instances, saving 100+ B per instance might help you keep your code in cache, in RAM, etc., rather than running out of memory and paging out half your data to swap.

As the other answer notes, you never actually accessed your attributes, so you weren't benchmarking slot access at all, which is why you saw no difference at all. Using `ipython3` `%%timeit` magic, I find that loading the `x` attribute of a given instance repeatedly is about 15% faster when it's slotted (33.5 ns with `__slots__` vs. 39.2 ns without), but that's only noticeable in microbenchmarks; it rarely matters in real code (where the actual work is doing a lot more than just attribute lookup). Reducing memory usage by a factor of 2-3x is a much bigger gain when it matters.

Answer (score 14):

1. The article you quoted says using slots provides for faster
   attribute **access** - you tested the time of object creation, and
   never accessed attributes of your object.
2. Testing a single operation is not statistically meaningful - measure the times of, say, 100000 operations.